# How to clamp camera rotation axis correctly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, game-development, quaternions

I am trying to clamp the X and Y axis of my camera, which I have managed to do. However, when the clamped value reaches the MAX threshold it will jump back to the MIN threshold!
Any idea what is causing this in my code?

```
 private void ClimbingLookRotation()
    {
        if (input.mouseX != 0 || input.mouseY != 0f)
        {
            orientation.rotation *= Quaternion.AngleAxis(input.mouseX, Vector3.up);
            orientation.rotation *= Quaternion.AngleAxis(input.mouseY, Vector3.right);
        }

        var rotX = orientation.eulerAngles.x;
        var rotY = orientation.eulerAngles.y;

        rotX = Mathf.Clamp(rotX, 1, 25);
        rotY = Mathf.Clamp(rotY, 200, 355);            

        orientation.eulerAngles = new Vector3(rotX, rotY, 0);
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something the works well so thought I'd answer in case it would help anyone!

```
 public static float ClampAngle(float angle, float min, float max)
    {   //Normalises angle value passed in between -180 to 180 to make the angle clampable
        angle = NormalizeAngle(angle);
        if (angle > 180)
        {
            angle -= 360;
        }
        else if (angle < -180)
        {
            angle += 360;
        }

        min = NormalizeAngle(min);
        if (min > 180)
        {
            min -= 360;
        }
        else if (min < -180)
        {
            min += 360;
        }

        max = NormalizeAngle(max);
        if (max > 180)
        {
            max -= 360;
        }
        else if (max < -180)
        {
            max += 360;
        }

        return Mathf.Clamp(angle, min, max);
    }

    public static float NormalizeAngle(float angle)
    { //If the angle is above or below 360 degrees, normalise it
        while (angle > 360)
            angle -= 360;
        while (angle < 0)
            angle += 360;
        return angle;
    }
```

And then just call the ClampAngle method where ever you need to clamp a value, for example:

```
private void ClimbingLookRotation()
    {
        if (input.mouseX != 0 || input.mouseY != 0f)
        {
            orientation.rotation *= Quaternion.AngleAxis(input.mouseX, Vector3.up);
            orientation.rotation *= Quaternion.AngleAxis(input.mouseY, Vector3.right);
        }

        var rotX = orientation.eulerAngles.x;
        var rotY = orientation.eulerAngles.y;

        rotX = HelperFunctions.ClampAngle(rotX, -10, 25); //Here
        rotY = HelperFunctions.ClampAngle(rotY, 200, 340); //And here

        orientation.eulerAngles = new Vector3(rotX, rotY, 0);
    }
```

I've called it in my camera rotation function to clamp both rotX and rotY, which is later applied to the rotation of my orientation game object.

Thankyou again to Ruzihm for your help before :)

Answer (score 0):

You could re-center your euler angles around the center value then clamp the difference:

```
float centralX = 13f;
float extentX = 12f;

float centralY = 277.5f;
float extentY = 77.5f;

private static float ClampEuler(float val, float center, float extent)
{
    return center + Mathf.Clamp((val - center + 360f) % 360f, -extent, extent);
}

private void ClimbingLookRotation()
{
    if (input.mouseX != 0 || input.mouseY != 0f)
    {
        orientation.rotation *= Quaternion.AngleAxis(input.mouseX, Vector3.up);
        orientation.rotation *= Quaternion.AngleAxis(input.mouseY, Vector3.right);
    }

    var rotX = orientation.eulerAngles.x;
    var rotY = orientation.eulerAngles.y;

    rotX = ClampEuler(rotX, centralX, extentX);
    rotY = ClampEuler(rotY, centralY, extentY);

    orientation.eulerAngles = new Vector3(rotX, rotY, 0);
}
```

By the way you may want to do `orientation.rotation *= Quaternion.AngleAxis(input.mouseY, orientation.right);` to rotate around the local right instead of global right. Rotating around global right may produce a rolling effect over time which you may not want.

Comment: Thankyou for your advice. I've tried to run it and I'm still getting the same issue, as soon as rotX or rotY reaches the extentX/extentY value it rapidly switches to its centraX/centralY value. I'm still getting used to using Quaternions so apologies if I am missing anything obvious. Thankyou again!